# $\{{x_n}\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence such that $|x_{n+1} - x_n| \leq \frac{1}{2} |x_n - x_{n-1}|.$ Prove ${x_n}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

This sequence appears Cauchy. But how to rigorously approach this problem.